# operation not permitted with unlink in codeigniter session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3, unlink

i am a application using codeigniter 3, while testing in xampp local server everything is fine but when i hosted in a server(live) facing an issue related to codeigniter session. when a user is logged in and performing actions suddenly a error `unlink(/tmp/ci_session..some file path here..):operation not permitted
Filename:drivers/Session_files_driver.php
Line Number: 354`
is coming, if refreshed the page error is vanished and everything is fine. any suggesstion is appreciated.

Comment: Check the permissions in the `/tmp` folder

Comment: actually there is no folder like tmp but it is showing the path likethat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value of `$config['sess_save_path']` in config.php. When using the files driver for sessions this must be set with the absolute path of the folder used to store session files. The folder must exist and its permissions must be set properly - try 0700.

[Documentation Here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#files-driver)

Comment: thanks for your answer,  i tried like as you mentioned, now i didn't get that error but there are some  session files creating in the folder which will become a headache if no  users are login and using it increases. so i want any other option.

Comment: The files that are created there will be cleaned up by the system eventually. Whether you use the database driver or file driver session info will exist for a certain amount of time after the session is closed. Trust the garbage collector!

Comment: i am using file driver the data in the files are cleaned after logout but files are still existing which is my problem(if no files increases then size of my application will increase).

Comment: This really isn't anything to worry about. The expired files will be deleted by the system eventually. These "empty" session files use very little disc space and will not affect the performance of your website. You can switch to database storage of session data but the same "problem" will occur - there will always be a collection of closed/expired session records in the session table.

Comment: can you send me the session configuration for files driver.

Comment: @prudhvi259, I have added another answer with configuration info. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the request for files driver configuration, in `application/config/config.php` options should be set as follows

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'sitesess'; //can be any string you like
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0; 
$config['sess_save_path'] = '/absolute/path/to/folder/for/session/files/;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 1800;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

See config.php for details on the various option values.

Cookie related variables in config.php are also important to proper Session functioning. In particular the following options are used by Session cookies.

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = '.example.com';  //for example
$config['cookie_path'] = '/';   //usually works
$config['cookie_secure'] =  FALSE; //Use TRUE to set cookie via HTTPS (server must be setup for SSL), otherwise set to FALSE
```

The folder where session files are stored must have the suitable permissions and ownership. See the [CodeIgniter documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#files-driver) for more information about permission, etc.